# How to share common parameters between two widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a following widget where if `animated = true` renders `AnimatedContainer` and if `animated = false` renders `Container`:

```
animated
        ? AnimatedContainer(
            duration: duration,
            decoration: decoration,
            child: child,
            margin: margin,
            padding: padding,
          )
        : Container(
            decoration: decoration,
            child: child,
            margin: margin,
            padding: padding,
          );
```

As you can see four parameters are common between these two widgets. Is there a way where I can store parameter in a variable and pass between them as one variable? So something like:

```
var params = (
  decoration: decoration,
  child: child,
  margin: margin,
  padding: padding,
);

animated
        ? AnimatedContainer(
            duration: duration,
            ...params,
          )
        : Container(params);
```

Comment: Did you try to use only AnimatedContainer with duration zero if not animated?

Comment: I believe you can't define the properties of a Widget that way. You either follow the suggestion above, or you do as you were doing in your own code. Defined the variables and re-use them in each Widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bloc for that.
Make a StreamController and wrap both the widgets inside StreamBuilder.
Now when you want to update the value just add value to StreamSink.

Code:

```
class AnimationBloc extends Bloc {
  StreamController _animationController = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();
  Stream get animationStream => _animationController.stream;
  StreamSink get animationStreamSink => _animationController.sink;
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.close();
  }
}
```

Where Block is:

```
abstract class Bloc {
  void dispose();
}
```

Now wrap the widgets with StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder<bool>(
   initialData: false,
   stream: AnimationBloc.animationStream,
   builder: (BuildContext context,
             AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
             return 
              snapshot.data
                ? AnimatedContainer(
                   duration: duration,
                   decoration: decoration,
                   child: child,
                   margin: margin,
                   padding: padding,
                 )
                : Container(
                   decoration: decoration,
                   child: child,
                   margin: margin,
                   padding: padding,
                );
             },
  ),
```

[Do the same for other widget]
and when you need to update the bool value `animated` to `true` just put it in `AnimationBloc.animationStreamSink.add(true)` it will get updated in both the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own widgets that return an animated widget or container, but that take as an argument some abstract data type you define that includes decoration, padding, child, and whatever else.

Here's an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyAnimatedContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Duration duration;
  final Params params;

  MyAnimatedContainer({this.duration = Duration(seconds:1), this.params}) : assert(params != null);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: duration,
      child: params.child,
      decoration: params.decoration,
      padding: params.padding,
    );
  }
}

class MyContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Params params;

  MyContainer(this.params) : assert(params != null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: params.child,
      decoration: params.decoration,
      padding: params.padding,
    );
  }
}


class Params {
  final Widget child;
  final Decoration decoration;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  Params({this.child, this.decoration, this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(12.0)}) : assert(child != null);
}
```

So you can define your parameters somehow:

```
Params containerParams = Params(child: SomeWidget(), decoration: Decoration(...), padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0));
```

And then use that params object to create your custom container widgets:

```
animated ? 
MyAnimatedContainer(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), params: containerParams) :
MyContainer(containerParams);
```